# Trying to add standard DOM event listener to monaco editor

Tags: javascript, events, monaco-editor

I'm trying to add focus / blur standard DOM events to monaco-editor.

```
editor.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    <do something>
});
```

I received the following answer:

***Uncaught TypeError: editor.addEventListener is not a function***

Also tried jquery

```
$(editor).on("blur", function(){
    <do something>
});
```

No errors this time, but nothing happens. I mean, the event didn't fire.

I've also tried to attach the listeners to editor container div, but same results.

any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In **Monaco Editor**

To listen for **focus event**, you can use

```
editor.onDidFocusEditorWidget(()=>{
     console.log("Focus event triggerd !")
})
```

and For **Blur event**, you can use

```
editor.onDidBlurEditorWidget(()=>{
     console.log("Blur event triggerd !")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Found them finally. Monaco Editor provides with two events:

```
editor.onDidBlurEditor(()=>{
   <do something>
});

editor.onDidFocusEditor(()=>{
   <do something>
});
```

I've finally discover them with Chrome DevTools checking the object properties. the api documentation available on project's git page is chinese for me.

Comment: This did not work for me, I had to add "Widget" or "Text" at the end for it to work